How does RDS Postgres OldestReplicationSlotLag metric correlate to replication slot Log Sequence Number lag?
We run a Postgres 14.9 database via RDS Aurora Serverless. We have a logical replication slot consumed by a service (Fivetran) every 15 minutes.
We noticed this behavior where the reported OldestReplicationSlotLag changes between a high steady state (~70MB of "lag"), to roughly half in magnitude. The dips correspond to when Fivetran syncs.

As an experiment, I started polling the database with the following query, every 10 seconds:
select NOW(), (pg_current_wal_lsn() - confirmed_flush_lsn) AS lag FROM pg_replication_slots

Here's a sample of the data
              now              |   lag
-------------------------------+----------
2024-10-07 20:24:52.364746+00 | 34418456
2024-10-07 20:25:02.709301+00 | 34427544
2024-10-07 20:25:13.149003+00 | 4040
...
2024-10-07 20:26:15.62648+00  | 41560
...
2024-10-07 20:27:49.353108+00 | 287760
...
2024-10-07 20:28:10.16838+00  | 32373144

The large spike is known behavior, due to a job that runs every 15 minutes. After that point, the incremental increases are fairly small until the next sync. So, I know the logical replication lag effectively drops to zero during a sync.
Comparing that with the metric, we can see:

When the LSN "lag" is ~32-34 million (Megabytes?), the metric is ~70 MB.
When the LSN lag is reset after a sync, the metric is ~36 MB.

How does the metric reported by RDS compare to the difference in LSN? And why does the "baseline" after a sync seem to be so large in magnitude?

Maybe they don't use confirmed_flush_lsn from pg_replication_slots, but some other LSN from pg_stat_replication.

@LaurenzAlbe From what I understand pg_stat_replication will have records if there is a process actively consuming a replication slot. At least, when I query it now in between syncs, there are no records. I was wondering, maybe RDS looks at the files on the file system (I'm not well versed) that pertain to the replication slot.

The joy of closed source, yes.
